# Error while Inserting Python List to Mysql

Tags: python, mysql

Have a Sample Python List as Follows:

```
data = [
('Jane','dffd','sdas','sdas'),
('Jane','dffd','sdas','sdas'),
('Jane','dffd','sdas','sdas')
]
```

Tried inserting this list onto a My Sql database with tablename 'test' as Follows:

```
import MySQLdb as my

db = my.connect()

cursor = db.cursor()

data = [
('Jane','dffd','sdas','sdas'),
('Jane','dffd','sdas','sdas'),
('Jane','dffd','sdas','sdas')
]

ddt = str(data)

cursor.executemany('INSERT into test VALUES(%s, %s, %s,%s)' %  ddt)

db.commit()  

db.close()
```

Getting an error saying:

```
not enough arguments for format string
```

Table contains 4 columns : test1,test2,test3,test4 .I know Im making a silly mistake someplace, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: `str(data)` doesn't do what you think it does. Use `cursor.executemany("INSERT into...)", data)` instead. See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT into test VALUES(%s, %s, %s,%s)',data)
```

Or

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES %s;" %(str(tuple(data)).replace('((','(').replace('))',')')))
```

Comment: Why the comma after 'data'? TypeError: executemany() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: To join the tuples with `,`

Comment: With the ',' , getting this :TypeError: executemany() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: same error:TypeError: executemany() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Thanks man , although its necessary to convert data to tuple? , I din't get that part.

Comment: Can try with `executemany` also. I added `executemany()` also

Answer (score 0):

Full code can be this type::

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
encoding = "utf8mb4"
db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host='',
    user='',
    passwd='',
    db='',
    compress=1,
    port=,
    charset='utf8mb4',
    use_unicode=True,
)
cursor = db.cursor()
data = [
('Jane','dffd','sdas','sdas'),
('Jane','dffd','sdas','sdas'),
('Jane','dffd','sdas','sdas')
]

sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES %s;" %(str(tuple(data)).replace('((','(').replace('))',')'))
print(sql) // you can print the sql query and verify to insert data on test mysqlworkbech for confirm data structure is 
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()  
db.close()
```